# Why is a weak* open set also norm open?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

> I want to show that a weak* open set is also norm open.

I know that if I consider the dual space $X^*$, then a neighbourhood basis of $f\in X^*$ is $\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$ with $\epsilon>0$ and $x_i\in X$ for all $i$.

Similarly a neighbourhood basis in the topology induced by the norm is  given by open balls.

Now my first question is, how can I think about the neighbourhood basis of $f\in X^*$?

> So I know that by definition $\mathcal{B}$ is a neighbourhood basis of $x$ in a topological space $X$ if $x\in V$ for all $V\in \mathcal{B}$ and for all neighbourhood $U\ni x$ there exists $V\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in V\subset U$.

But in our case I don't see how the neighbourhoods in the weak* topology looks like.

Additionaly I don't see how to show that a set which is weak* open also is norm open.

Could maybe someone answer my two questions?

Comment: There is no "the neighbourhood basis". What you have is "**one** neighbourhood basis". **A** neighbourhood basis of $f$ is a "nicely choosen" family of neighbourhoods of $f$ that work just like the (family of) balls of radius $1/n$.

Comment: @AndréCaldas I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to know how exactly a weak* open set looks like.

$\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$ is open in the norm topology whenever $l\in \mathbb N$,   $\epsilon>0$ and $x_i\in X$ for all $i$. This is because $g \mapsto g(x_i)$ is a continuous function for the norm topology . [$\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}=\bigcap_{1\leq i \leq l} \{g: g(x_i) \in (B(f(x_i),\epsilon))\}$].  Any open set in a topological space is a union of basic neighborhoods of its points.

Comment: If you say any weak* open set is a union of sets of the form $\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$, then over what is this union, over $l$ and $\epsilon$?

Comment: Over some collection of $l, \epsilon$ and the points $x_i$.  @user123234

Comment: But this set $\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$ is only a neighbourhoodbasis of $f$, but I only know that for a basis every open set can be written as a union f basis elements, so why can we say any open set is a union of $\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$ since this is not a basis for the weak* topology.

Comment: That is exactly what I am using. Any open set is a union of basic open sets. @user123234

Comment: But I only know that a open set $O$ in any topological space $T$ can be written as $O=\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha$ where $V_\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis. But in our case we only have a neighbourhood basis.

Comment: @user123234 $O$ is also a union of basic neighborhoods of its points since $x \in O$ implies there is a basic neighborhood $V_x$ such that $V_x \subseteq O$.

Comment: Ah okey I see what you mean an then in our case the basic neighbourhoods are unions of $\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$ and any open set $O$ can be written as a union of its basic neighbourhoods for all $x\in O$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @user123234

Comment: But now one last question, why does $g\mapsto g(x_i)$ continuous helps me to show that $\{g\in X^*:|g(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon, 1\leq i\leq l\}$ is open in the norm topology?